# how to display / Select a MYSQL query horizontally

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently extracting some timetable information from my database.
I am facing a problem that I need the rows in cols and  cols in rows.

The query is as:

```
SELECT `courses`.`course_id`,`faculty`.`uName`,`rooms`.`room_name`,`slot_allocs`.`slot_num`
FROM `faculty`
    LEFT JOIN `courses` ON `courses`.`fac_id` = `faculty`.`uName`
    LEFT JOIN `depts` ON `faculty`.`dept_code` = `depts`.`dept_code`
    LEFT JOIN `slot_allocs` ON `slot_allocs`.`course_id` = `courses`.`course_id`
    LEFT JOIN `rooms` ON `slot_allocs`.`room` = `rooms`.`room_name`
    LEFT JOIN `slots` ON `slot_allocs`.`table_name` = `slots`.`table_name` AND         `slot_allocs`.`day` = `slots`.`day` AND `slot_allocs`.`slot_num` =     `slots`.`slot_num`
WHERE `slot_allocs`.`day` = 1  AND `depts`.`dept_code` = 100

ORDER BY `slots`.`slot_num` ASC
```

After I execute my PHP file in which this query executes it's in a sequential retrieve and show, I would like to have the output -- >  one after the another

```
> > **I want to align in the sequential manner of the period  per day like this:
> >|---------------------------------------------
> >day 1| period 1 |period 2 |period 3 |period 4| 
> >|----|----------|---------|---------|--------|
> >day 2| period 1 |period 2 |period 3 |period 4|
> >|---------------------------------------------
```

And this is my php code:

```
$sql = file_get_contents("eboard.sql");
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo " Course: ID ". $row["course_id"]." : ";     
        echo " Prof.:". $row["uName"]." : ";
        echo " Room :".$row["room_name"]." : ";
        echo " period".$row["slot_num"]."";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
} else
    echo "0 results";
$conn->close();
```

The output i get : ---
[image]

Please help !!

Comment: Ok, so the HTML is correct and only the CSS is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So this code should do it. You should read up on how tables works. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) have a simple page about it. I hope this version is what you want. It is not a full solution but it shows you how to use tables.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "  <tr>";
    echo "    <th>Course</th>";
    echo "    <th>Prof.</th>";
    echo "    <th>Room</th>";
    echo "    <th>Period</th>";
    echo "  </tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "    <td>Course: ID ". $row["course_id"]."</td>";     
        echo "    <td>Prof.:". $row["uName"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>Room :".$row["room_name"]."</td>";
        echo "    <td>period".$row["slot_num"]."</td>";
        echo "  </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: yeah, but I want the period to aligned vertically.

Comment: Then add a <br> when you want the break. But if i was you i would remove the TABLE tag and use a DIV. Then add some Bootstrap, http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Or do you want like 4 columns on the table? I am not sure i understand.

Comment: I have updated the out format, please give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<table>` out of the loop:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo " Course: ID ". $row["course_id"]." : ";     
        echo " Prof.:". $row["uName"]." : ";
        echo " Room :".$row["room_name"]." : ";
        echo " period".$row["slot_num"]."";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not work. The same thing happens.

Comment: @ibrahimhaleemkhan Would you explain it's difference with what you want? If it's hard to explain add examples from what you want and what you get to the question. Use real names not period 1, period 2, etc.